# Deploy questions with a quiz application

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building a quiz app that has thousands of questions. The questions are in a text file like so:

```
42. Example question?
a) option 1
b) option 2+
c) option 3
d) option 4
e) option 5

43. Example question?
a) option 1
b) option 2
c) option 3
d) option 4+
e) option 5
```

The `+` character indicates the correct answer. My application has a `Question` class:

```
data class Question(
    val text: String?,
    val answers: ArrayList<String>?,
    val correctAnswer: String?
)
```

My goal is to ship the application with all those questions and the questions are not user-editable. What is the best way to achieve that?

A couple of things that I can think of:

- I can prove the text file with the app and parse questions at runtime with some regex. Seems possible but messy and possibly slow. It also won't scale well.
- Somehow populate a database with these `Question` objects and ship the database with the application. Again, it sounds feasible but I am not sure if this is actually possible.
- Something else? Maybe serialization or something like that? I am not sure. The `Question` class does implement the `Parcelable` interface. I am new to Android development; there's most likely something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow populate a database with these Question objects and ship the database with the application. Again, it sounds feasible but I am not sure if this is actually possible.

In terms of SQLite:

- There are SQLite client libraries for most major programming languages. You can write a desktop tool that converts the questions into table rows using your favorite language.
- You can package that SQLite database with your app and copy it to the filesystem for use. Room has built-in support for that (`createFromAsset()` on `RoomDatabase.Builder`), if you wish to use Room for your SQLite access API.

Alternatively, you could have a desktop tool convert your questions into JSON or XML, then package those as assets and read them in at runtime.

Comment: If I use Room for SQLite access, does it matter how I create the database on my desktop computer?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert: Room has some metadata that needs to go in the database. The documentation for `createFromAsset()` is a bit murky on that point. What I have done is have Room create an empty database for me, but with my table structure and with Room's metadata. I copy that database off the device and pour my data into it, then use the populated database as an asset going forward. This is going to be annoying if you have frequent schema changes, though.